# Is it possible to combine an Arrayformula, with a Transpose and a Sequence?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sequence, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Could someone help me out?

My goal is to generate transposed arrays of dates between (&including) the start- and end date for each row.

My source data has two columns, a start date and an end date, like this:

[image: Two columns, column A being the start date of a period, column B the end date]

I have it working for a single column, using `sequence+transpose (transpose(sequence(B1-A1+1,1,A1+1)))`. which gives

[image: this]

as a result. I have also tried using a [different method](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/auto-populate-dates-between-two-given-dates-in-google-sheets/) of generating the date, but that also gave a single row, not expandable to an array.

Wrapping either formula in an arrayformula does not work. Am I doing something wrong or is there simply no way to get this working with an array of start- and end dates?

For reference, this is how I wrote the formulas with the arrayformula:

- Using sequence:

  ```
  arrayformula(transpose(sequence(B1:B2-A1:A2+1,1,A1:A2+1)))
  ```
- Using date_dif:

  `arrayformula(transpose(arrayFormula(to_date(row(indirect("A"&A1:A2):indirect("A"&B1:B2))))))`

Does anyone know if this is possible at all?

Comment: It's just a  format issue right? can you share a demo sheeet with your desired input & output? (turn sharing on :))

Comment: @Datanovice looks like his problem is: `Sequence` doesn't work with `ArrayFormula` because `Sequence` already has it's own peculiar array behavior.

Comment: @datanovice Added!

Comment: @YannickNierop looks like your date_dif function is not working arrayformula or not... how about making one that works without array first?

Comment: @CodeCamper I've added the date_dif to the demo file, it works as it should for a single row.

Comment: @YannickNierop are you ever going to have overlapping dates, is there any other patterns here?

Comment: @CodeCamper on a single row? No. On multiple rows there might be overlapping dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(IFERROR(IF(
 REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(REPT(1, DAYS(B3:B, A3:A)), 
 REPT("(.)", DAYS(B3:B, A3:A)))*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(IFERROR(DAYS(B3:B, A3:A))))))-1)), "^-1$", )="",,
 REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(REPT(1, DAYS(B3:B, A3:A)), 
 REPT("(.)", DAYS(B3:B, A3:A)))*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(IFERROR(DAYS(B3:B, A3:A))))))-1)), "^-1$", )+A3:A))))
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PhNgW-RKuefoko5rHqitClz5kYxkKBy_IjbGuQWuSiE/copy)

Comment: Thank you! I have marked this as the answer since this is the only one that does not use additional column references (since the amount of dates between may very well exceed Z this would give additional problems).

Comment: btw this would also work: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B3:B="",,IFERROR(IF(COLUMN(A:ZZZ)-1>DAYS(B3:B, A3:A),,A3:A+COLUMN(A:ZZZ)-1))))` if the date difference is less than 18279 days

Comment: @player0 I don't understand, if the date difference is greater than 18279 days won't you run out of columns to display it the way he wants to anyway? Also I'm not understanding why your shorter answer is not the best answer?

Answer (score 1):

This was going to be my effort but @player0 got there first as always:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="","",if(column(C2:Z)-column(C2:C)>B2:B-A2:A,"",A2:A+column(C2:Z)-column(C2:C))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B3:B="",,IFERROR(IF(COLUMN(A:Z)-1>DAYS(B3:B, A3:A),,A3:A+COLUMN(A:Z)-1))))
```

[image]